# How to solve fatal: unable to access, Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, github

When I try to get a pull form master using `git pull origin master` I get the following proxy error.

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT`

I'm working on a macOS Mojave and I haven't configured any proxy servers either. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check `git config http.proxy` — is anything configured? Check `echo $http_proxy`, `echo $https_proxy`, `echo $all_proxy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of some proxy configurations this occurs, to reset all the configurations just run `rm ~/.gitconfig` and start the terminal again.

Answer (score 6):

> just run rm ~/.gitconfig

Maybe try instead:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Check with git config -l --show-origin|grep -i proxy, to be sure you didn't missed anything.

The point is: that would be less "destructive" than  `rm ~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted pc, and it worked.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do what I did - I tried to set up a proxy on an Azure Virtual Desktop - as it's VPN it was already set up on a proxy! After removing the extra proxy settings in my .gitconfig file I was able to connect successfully.
I know this isn't what you necessarily experienced, but this was the first thread I saw when googling, so I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this may not strictly answer the question, it does seem like a good 'gotcha' to be aware of.